My next question on a sacrifice
I'm just staring at this sacrifice without seeing the solution, anyone kindly help to me ?
[fen "4r1k1/3b1p2/6p1/1BPpn2p/7n/r3PqN1/2Q1RPPP/1R3NK1 w - - 0 1"]
[Startflipped "1"]


now black threatens Qxg2 mate. w doesnt have anything better than taking Q. Nexf3 Kh1. now comes Bh3 with mate threat with Bg2. try to see if there is a way out for white

@cmgchess Take black b at g2 by k ?

Bg2 is defended by the knight on h4.

@Hank'sbackrank Right, I just confused the 2 knights on the board.

If you can't solve a problem I suggest you learn how to use an engine - if you get stuck (and only use the engine once you get stuck) it will show you the wining line almost instantly. The set of tools on lichess is a good place to start

I was sure this classical sacrifice was from a Brois Spassky's game but I cannot find a reference.

Black can force checkmate. After 1. gxf3 Nexf3+ 2. Kh1 Bh3 nothing white can do can prevent Bg2#. The most white can do is delay by a move with a spite check sacrificing the queen
[fen "4r1k1/3b1p2/6p1/1BPpn2p/7n/r3PqN1/2Q1RPPP/1R3NK1 w - - 0 1"]
[Startflipped "1"]

1. gxf3 Nexf3+ 2. Kh1 Bh3 3. Qxg6+ fxg6 4. null Bg2#

